# Android differentiate between navigate with argument and navigateUp

Tags: android-architecture-navigation, android-navigation, android-navigation-graph

I am using the Android Navigation component moving from fragment to fragment in my app

So, I have a fragment defined something like this

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/my_fragment_dest"
    android:name="com.mycompany.myapp.view.fragment.main.MyFragment"
    tools:layout="@layout/my_fragment" >
    <argument android:name="doSpecialThing"
        app:argType="boolean"
        app:nullable="false"
        android:defaultValue="false"/>
</fragment>
```

and a start fragment like this

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/home_dest"
    android:name="com.mycompany.myapp.view.fragment.main.StartFragment"
    tools:layout="@layout/start_fragment">
    <action
        android:id="@+id/action_home_dest_to_my_fragment_dest"
        app:launchSingleTop="true"
        app:destination="@id/my_fragment_dest" />
</fragment>
```

and then in onViewCreated of MyFragment I check the value:

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    doSpecialThing =
        arguments?.let { MyFragmentArgs.fromBundle(it).doSpecialThing} ?: false
}
```

This fragment can be called from the "start" screen, in which case I want to do the special thing, so I call

```
    val bundle = bundleOf(
        "doSpecialThing" to true
    )
    findNavController().navigate(
        R.id.action_home_dest_to_my_fragment_dest,
        bundle, animationThing()
    )
```

but it also calls other fragments, and when they are finished they go back to it calling

```
    findNavController().navigateUp()
```

But for some reason, although navigateUp doesn't include any bundle, and the default in the navigation xml file is "false" I still get "doSpecialThing" set to "true"

I would prefer not to explicitly call the navigate with a bundle set to false for all the "back" cases - is there a way to make it clear tha tI got to this fragment via "back" or "navigateUp"

Thanks